# My query runs in MySQL Workbench but doesn't inside my VB.NET code, I'm trying to join 3 variables content into a single row

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a program that reads data and input into a database, this is my query:

```
Dim command As New MySqlCommand("UPDATE long_short_parameters SET ativo_compra = '" & ativo_compra & "', ativo_venda = '" & ativo_venda & "', ratio_entrada = '" & ratio_entrada & "', ratio_stop = '" & ratio_stop & "', ratio_alvo_saida = '" & ratio_alvo_saida & "', title_operation = '" & title_operation & "', data_hora = '" & data & "'  WHERE id = '" & id & "'", connection)
```

I get this error message:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CMIG4 x '03/12/2021 14:30:09 '', data_hora = '03/12/2021 14:30:09',  WHERE id = ' at line 1
```

But when I run it in mysql workbench, it works fine (as long as i do replace the variable with the proper values)

```
14:47:57    UPDATE long_short_parameters SET ativo_compra = 'CMIG4', ativo_venda = 'CSAN3', ratio_entrada = '0.45', ratio_stop = '0.40', ratio_alvo_saida = '0.12', title_operation = 'CMIG4 x CSAN3', data_hora = '03/12/2021 14:30:09'  WHERE id = '13'   1 row(s) affected Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0  0.141 sec
```

This is where the variables have their values attached

```
Dim id = DataGridView2.Rows(DataGridView2.CurrentCellAddress.Y).Cells(0).Value
        Dim ativo_compra = DataGridView2.Rows(DataGridView2.CurrentCellAddress.Y).Cells(2).Value
        Dim ativo_venda = DataGridView2.Rows(DataGridView2.CurrentCellAddress.Y).Cells(3).Value
        Dim ratio_entrada = DataGridView2.Rows(DataGridView2.CurrentCellAddress.Y).Cells(4).Value
        Dim ratio_stop = DataGridView2.Rows(DataGridView2.CurrentCellAddress.Y).Cells(5).Value
        Dim ratio_alvo_saida = DataGridView2.Rows(DataGridView2.CurrentCellAddress.Y).Cells(6).Value
        Dim data = System.DateTime.Now
        Dim title_operation = "'" & ativo_compra & " x " & ativo_venda & " x " & data & "'"
```

My job depends on this so I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Your query fails because you don't use parameters. One of your values contains one or more single quotes and this confuse the parser because it cannot make sense of something with _'CMIG4 x '03/12/2021 14:30:09 ''_ Use always a parameterized query because that's just the simpler problem that can arise when you concatenate strings to form an sql command. Search for Sql Injection .

Comment: I need that "ativo_compra" and "ativo_venda" (wich means buy asset and sell asset! it's a software for a stock market company) goes to a row (title_operation) with the current date. So we know when that operation was made

Comment: As I have said, the only sensible solution is to use parameters. There are many examples around here

Answer (score 1):

Your query fails because you don't use parameters. One of your values contains one or more single quotes and this confuse the parser because it cannot make sense of something like

```
...title = 'CMIG4 x '03/12/2021 14:30:09 ''...
```

Where does the string value starts and where does it ends?.

The single quotes around the date fool the parser that believes the value ends after *x '* Then it meets some text that cannot be interpreted as a valid sql syntax.
So the only sensible option is to use always a parameterized query because the code above is just one of the many problems that can arise when you concatenate strings to form an sql command.

For example look at what an [Sql Injection hack](https://xkcd.com/327/) could do to your db.

Here a trace how you should do it.
First create the command and remove all the concatenations from the commandtext. Insert a parameter placeholder instead of the variables.

```
 Dim command As New MySqlCommand("UPDATE long_short_parameters 
            SET ativo_compra = @ativo, ativo_venda = @venda, 
                ratio_entrada = @ratio_e, ratio_stop = @ratio_s,  
                ratio_alvo_saida = @ratio_as, title_operation = @title, 
                data_hora = @data  WHERE id = @id", connection)
```

Now you have a single "non concatenated" string easy to read and understand. In the next step you add the parameters and their values
to the command.

```
command.Parameters.Add("@ativo", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ativo_compra
command.Parameters.Add("@venda", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ativo_venda
... and continue with the others parameter placeholders
```

Finally you can execute the command

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Notice that I have used MySqlDbType.VarChar to define the parameters value type. This should be adjusted to match the real type of the fields. Visual Studio Intellisense should give your the hint for the enum values to use.

Comment: Thank you for the lesson! I'll use from now on. But when i run i get this error: 

MySqlException was unhandled
Fatal error encountered during command execution.

My code it's like this: https://pastebin.com/SK9XDReU

Comment: I can see two errors: The parameter placeholder is `ratio_s` but you add `ratio_stop`, then, after the last parameter placeholder and before the WHERE there is a comma that shouldn't be there